# Increasing the size of /var/ on centos7

Tags: centos, docker, centos7, docker-compose

I'm running docker containers on my machine which puts it all in /var/. `df` shows that /var/ is only 5G but I know the total amount of this system if 40G and it has at least 24G available. How can increase the size of /var/ an extra 15G? I'm unclear on if I should be doing this in my docker-compose file or through CentOS itself. The docker documentation on filesystems is incredibly confusing.

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   27G  2.9G   24G  11% /
/dev/mapper/centos-var   5.0G  4.1G  944M  82% /var

pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  <39.50g 4.00m

vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  centos   1   4   0 wz--n- <39.50g 4.00m
```

Comment: Is this a VM or a physical machine? Add the output of `pvs` and `vgs` to your question.

Comment: @NasirRiley it's a VM. I edited the question with the output of the commands.

Comment: Your `centos` volume group is out of space. There are two other logical volumes in that volume group, most likely `centos-home` and `centos-tmp`, that are taking up the rest of the 40GB. You'll need to add a new virtual disk to your VM, create a new physical volume, add it to the `centos` volume group, and expand some of the free space to `centos-var`.

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation, I can see there are lots of unused space is there in **/** partition so we can reduce this LV and make use this reclaimed space to extend **/var**

Step 1. Reduce LV  **"centos-root"** 
Results >> you will get enough space in VG **"Centos"**

Step 2. Esxtend the size of LV **"centos-var"**

**Note: You have to take precautions as you are reducing the / partition.**

Comment: If the file system on `centos-root` is `xfs` then it won't be possible to reduce the size.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a VM hopefully you can just add one more disk to it and use that space to extend the volume. Here is a description how you can extend: https://www.linuxtechi.com/extend-lvm-partitions/

Alternatively you can move the docker files to somewhere where you have enough space. (In your case it's only the `/` dir, what I wouldn't suggest to use, but may work as an emergency solution for short time):

1. Stop all containers and the `dockerd` too
2. Move all docker files:

```
mv /var/lib/docker/ /somewhere/you/have/space/
```

3. Create a symlink to the new dir:

```
ln -s /somewhere/you/have/space/docker /var/lib/docker
```

4. Restart `dockerd` and the containers.